# Firestore rules: Allow only append new keys to a map field

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing a chat system using Firestore. For each user account there is a document that contains the user open chats in a map field called `channels`.

Every time a user wants to talk to someone, the document id of the new room is appended to both users `channels` map. In order to protect that map and prevent someone tampering or deleting the entire map, I would like to set a rule that only new values could be added, but none removed. Is it possible?

This is my current schema:

- users (collection)

  - userID (document)

    - channels (field, map)

      - channel1ID

        - name
        - lastAccess
      - channel2ID

        - name
        - lastAccess
      - ...
- channels (collection)

  - channelID (document)

    - messages (collection)

Comment: I think this is a bad database design.. learn more about compose keys, it would helps you to enforce one-to-one relationship

Comment: Can you post an example about how to achieve this using composite keys?